# ¿Como poner un color de fondo a un texto en un PdfContentByte de ItextSharp en C#?

Tags: c#, itextsharp

Buenas.

Estoy creando un PDF con ItextSharp 5.5.10 y en el tengo que incluir textos con un fondo blanco en determinadas posiciones. La pagina del PDF contiene una imagen de fondo. Para ello estoy usando PdfContentByte pero no consigo que me pinte el fondo blanco.

```
PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
cb.BeginText();
cb.SetTextMatrix(cuadroTexto.PosX, defaultHeight - (cuadroTexto.PosY + cuadroTexto.Alto));
Font font = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8.25f, BaseColor.BLACK);
cb.SetFontAndSize(font.BaseFont, 8.25f);
cb.ShowText(cuadroTexto.Texto);
cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.WHITE); // Aqui intento ponerle el blanco pero lo ignora
cb.EndText();
```

¿Hay alguna manera de hacerlo con PdfContentByte o tengo que recurrir a pintar un regtangulo blanco a mano?

PD: Por si sirve estoy usando Visual Studio 2013 Express

**UPDATE 1**

He probado con `cb.Fill();` tal como me recomiendan abajo y sigue sin colorearse.

Comment: No olvides llamar al método fill(): cb.fill()

Comment: @GabrielMolina lo he puesto y sigue sin colorearlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que ya he encontrado una solución.

El problema venia porque estaba intentando hacer 2 cosas a la vez (insertar el texto y poner el recuadro de fondo blanco). Separandolo en 2 acciones con estados funciona perfectamente.

```
PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
cb.SaveState();
cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.WHITE);
cb.Rectangle(cuadroTexto.PosX, defaultHeight - (cuadroTexto.PosY + cuadroTexto.Alto), cuadroTexto.Ancho, cuadroTexto.Alto);
cb.Fill();
cb.RestoreState();

cb.BeginText();
cb.SetTextMatrix(cuadroTexto.PosX, defaultHeight - (cuadroTexto.PosY + 9));
Font font = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8.25f, BaseColor.BLACK);
cb.SetFontAndSize(font.BaseFont, 8.25f);
cb.ShowText(cuadroTexto.Texto);
cb.EndText();
```